# Why I often asked for password when trying to do teamviewer to my coworker's computer?

Tags: passwords, teamviewer

It only happens in one computer. I am never asked for password on others.

I got this message

the password you have entered is invalid

Then I got to ask my employee what's the password and he gave me a changing one.

I wonder if there is some settings or something. His computer is listed in one of my account.

How do I set that his computer do not change teamviewer password?

Answer (score 0):

While connected to that machine, open the TeamViewer program and configure unattended access. This will allow you to set a static password, which is separate from the one randomly generated on the main screen.

Here's the official cheatsheet:

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/res/pdf/first_steps_unattended_access_en.pdf